# Searching Algorithm C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have problem i want to use bool function to create searching algorithm
this is my code

```
private bool IsEqual(int data1, int[] arr2){
     bool find=false;

        foreach(int data2 in arr2){
           if(data1==data2){
              find=true;
              break;
              }
     }

     return find;
}
```

and this is i call the function

```
int data1=2;
int[] arr={1,2,3,4,5};
if(IsEqual(data1, arr)){
    console.writeline("Find in index");
 }
```

how can i get the index of the array if the number is find?

Note:

- I must use bool function
- I can't add parameter in bool function
- i can't add keyword in parameter like ref int data1
- only change bool function
- I can't add other function

Comment: I don't know if you're doing this for learning or what, but you could just use [`Array.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx)

Comment: I use this algorithm for my project this is not my real project just examples

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't given us enough information about the constraints. It sounds like your professor has made the `IsEqual` method a black box. You can only return `bool` and you aren't allowed to use an `out` parameter. What *are* you allowed to do?

Comment: that's makes me confused

Comment: If you have to find the index and must use only the functions provided, and aren't allowed to search for yourself, what about passing in successively larger sub-arrays of the array? When it goes from false to true, you have your index.

Comment: Taekhan - clever, but of course spectacularly inefficient. If that's the answer, the Professor is encouraging them to write very bad code.

Comment: On the other hand, at least your solution meets the problem constraints, unlike all the other answers. So whilst its not a great solution, its the only correct one I have seen so far.

Comment: If you can't change the signature of the `IsEqual` method, you cannot return an int from it. You need to go back to your professor and ask what s/he means you to do. The question as it is is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

You can return `index`. Return -1 if not found (instead of false)

Comment: but my lecturer told me I must return bool not int

Comment: After `IsEqual` returns `true`, you may call another function that returns `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain count yourself, or switch to use a `for(int i=...` loop:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(int data2 in arr2) {
    if( data2 == data1 ) return i;
    i++;
}
return -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

C# has a notion of ref arguments: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx.

```
private bool IsEqual(ref int data1, int[] arr2) {
    bool find=false;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++) {
        if(data1==arr2[i]) {
            find=true;
            data1 = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!find) {
        data1 = -1;
    }
    return find;
}
```

and this can be called like so

```
int data1=2;
int[] arr={5,4,3,2,1};
if(IsEqual(ref data1, arr)){
    console.writeline("Find in index");
}
int index = data1;
```

Comment: but my lecturer told me I can't add parameter in bool function

Comment: if you can't add a parameter to the bool function, are you allowed to pass one of the arguments by reference? I've edited the code sample to demonstrate

Comment: I must use bool IsEqual(int data1, int[] arr2) I can't add another keyword in parameter function

Answer (score 0):

Use [an `out` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) combined with a `for` loop. Play with it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IEiRLN). The `out` parameter lets you keep return a `bool`, and the `for` loop is built for keeping track of the array index.

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    // this is your method
    // using an out parameter and a for loop
    // ignore the static keyword - it isn't important for the example
    private static bool IsEqual(int data1, int[] arr2, out int index)
    {
        index = -1;
        bool find = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (data1 == arr2[i])
            {
                find = true;
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        // you don't need to return the index
        // the out parameter covers that for you
        return find;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // and this is i call the function 
        int data1 = 2;
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        int index;
        if (IsEqual(data1, arr, out index))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Find in index {0}", index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but my lecturer told me I can't add parameter in bool function

Answer (score 0):

OK, given your strange constraints, here's some code that finds the index of your int, "using" your `IsEqual` function:

```
int data1=2;
int[] arr={1,2,3,4,5};
for (int ix = 0; ix < arr.Length; ix++) {
    if(IsEqual(data1, new int[] { arr[ix] })) {
        Console.WriteLine("Find in index {0}", ix);
        break;
    }
}
```

It's pretty terrible code, but it does what you want..

Comment: I'm sorry but i only must change the bool function not the main

Comment: Well, what does your professor expect you to do with the index then? You can't return it, are you supposed to just print it from inside the function?

Comment: You can't. Index is an integer. You are returning a bool. You could save it to a global variable, but I **really** hope that's not what your professor intended (though if he wrote `IsEqual`, maybe he does).